# MongoDB Aggregation - Perform sum for the value in the objects with dynamic keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have the following collection with `_id` and `traits`.

```
[
    {
      _id: 1,
      traits: {
        Rarity: {
          infoin: 15,
        },
        Type: {
          iron: 3,
          sliver: 5,
          wood: 7,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      traits: {
        Cloth: {
          barron1: 11,
          barron2: 12,
        },
        Hair: {
          black: 6,
          yellow: 9,
          red: 8
        }
      },
    },
    ...
]
```

As you can see keys of `traits` are dynamic and the keys of sub-objects as well.

Here is the result I wanna get:

```
[
    {
      _id: 1,
      traits: 15,
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      traits: 23
    }
]
```

> Tip:
>
> infocoin = iron + sliver + wood
>
> barron1 + barron2 = black + yellow + red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$set` - Set `traitObjs` array field by converting the object to array via `$objectToArray`.
2. `$set` - Set `firstTraitValues` field by getting the value of first document from `traitObjs` array, then converting from object to array via `$objectToArray`.
3. `$project` - Decorate the output document. Set `traits` field by converting `firstTraitValues` array to number type with `$reduce` and `$sum` all the `v` values.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      traitObjs: {
        $objectToArray: "$traits"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      firstTraitValues: {
        $objectToArray: {
          $first: "$traitObjs.v"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      traits: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$firstTraitValues",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $sum: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this.v"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k0p-2sgeeNC)

---

Since all the values in the first key document and the second key document of `traits` are the same,

> infocoin = iron + sliver + wood
>
> barron1 + barron2 = black + yellow + red

Hence the above approach just sums up all the values in the first key document of `traits`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it's working well.
But I wanna ask you if your answer is optimized...
Is there any better answers?
Actually I have many many documents in this collection

Answer (score 0):

This answer is really the same as @yong-shun's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72421132/1409374) but it composes everthing into one `"$project"`.  I don't know if it would be more efficient or not.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "traits": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {
            "$objectToArray": {
              "$getField": {
                "field": "v",
                "input": { "$first": { "$objectToArray": "$traits" } }
              }
            }
          },
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": { "$sum": [ "$$value", "$$this.v" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/H11Zd2aaoS4).